# I want to convert 1 column into multiple columns

Tags: sql, oracle

If source table t1 is this:

```
| col1    |
+---------+
| 2-3-4-5 |
| 6-7     |
| 8       |
| 9       |
```

then output should be in 4 columns:-

```
| col1 | col2 | col3 | col4 |
+------+------+------+------+
| 2    |  3   |  4   |  5   |
| 6    |  7   |      |      |
| 8    |      |      |      |
| 9    |      |      |      |
```

Comment: Tough luck. At least you've now learned not to store data like dash separated items.

Comment: Tag the dbms you're using. Some product have their own functionality that may become handy here.

Comment: I am using Oracle Database 11g Enterprise Edition Release 11.2.0.1.0 - 64bit. 

SQL> select * from new_tab;
STR
------------
1-2-3-4
4-5-6
6-7
7
SQL>

Answer (score 2):

It is not the direct answer to the question still, I would like to make a note. If you can leverage ETL tools, it will really be easier and will give you lot of control over the transformation of data.
You can have a different kind of data in source eg. `2-3-4, 5, 6-7` or `1 2 3, 45 1, 21 10` (or anything in that matter) and transform it.